# Unterschied zwischen "unvermeidlich" und "unvermeidbar"

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "unvermeidlich" und "unvermeidbar"?

Im Duden gibt es keine Beispiele für "unvermeidbar". Allerdings habe ich im linguee.de nachgeschlagen und diese Beispiele gefunden.

> Beispiel 1: Leider waren Kürzungen des Etats unvermeidbar.
>   Beispiel 2: Mit so einem engen Zeitplan scheint Stress unvermeidbar.

Meine Frage ist folgende - kann "unvermeidbar" durch "unvermeidlich" ersetzt werden? Und wann sind sie nicht austauschbar? Und noch etwas - nachdem ich alles über "unvermeidlich" gelesen habe, verstehe ich dieses Adjektiv auf folgende Weise: "unvermeidlich" impliziert Schicksal (äußere Kraft), aber auch Kausalität.

Comment: Ich sehe es genau so wie Du: »unvermeidlich« bei äußeren, kaum oder gar nicht zu beeinflussenden Umständen; »unvermeidbar« wenn es durchaus in jemandes Macht stünde, irgendwas zu vermeiden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In diesem Fall gibt es keinen klaren Unterschied. Generell gibt es Worte, bei denen die Endung einen Unterschied ausmacht (z.b. löslich - lösbar), unvermeidlich gehört nicht direkt dazu. Es gibt einen haarfeinen Unterschied [siehe Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unvermeidlich#Bedeutung1a)

> sich aus etwas als sichere, in Kauf zu nehmende Folge ergebend
> Beispiel:
> unvermeidliche Härtefälle

In diesem Fall wäre unvermeidbar falsch.

Ich persönlich verwende "unvermeidbar" bei Ereignissen, die ich nicht umgehen kann. "Unvermeidlich" verwende ich eher wenn der Zustand von etwas beschrieben wird.

Comment: Ich glaube, die Antwort liegt im letzten Satz.

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke es ist wie bei verzeihlich und verzeihbar.
Ersteres birgt die Anlage verziehen zu werden, letzteres verweist auf die Möglichkeit.

Unvermeidlich birgt die Anlage, nicht vermieden werden zu können;
unvermeidbar bedeutet das Fehlen einer Möglichkeit zu meiden.

Macht das für jemanden Sinn ?